# trouble rearranging my 2x2 matrix in a simple way in R

Tags: r, matrix, cbind

I'm trying to turn

```
df<-matrix(1:4,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
df
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

into

```
matrix(c(2,4,1,3),nrow = 1,ncol = 4)
2    4    1    3
```

so that i can run it through a `for` loop to `rbind` many entries.

I've been trying

```
cbind(df[row 2,],df[row 1,])
```

but it's not working. Is there a simple way to do this that won't require me to separate the matrix and then bring it back together?

Comment: Try with `t(c(t(df[ncol(df):1, ])))`

Comment: @akrun yes that worked, thanks!

Comment: You can perhaps do `cbind(tail(df, 1), head(df, 1))`.

Comment: Or `rev(t(df[, 2:1]))`

Comment: @markus That is very compact.  You should post as an answer

Comment: @markus Yes, you should.

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic ok peer pressure became too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way. Without the call to `matrix` it returns a vector, not a matrix.

```
df <- matrix(1:4, 2)

matrix(c(t(df[nrow(df):1,])), 1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    4    1    3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
t(c(t(df[nrow(df):1, ])))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    4    1    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Turning a comment into an answer, a fourth option is

```
rev(t(m[, ncol(m):1]))
# [1] 2 4 1 3
```

with

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
r <- unlist(rev(data.frame(t(df))))
```

or

```
r <- do.call(c,rev(split(df,1:nrow(df))))
```

or

```
r <- unlist(rev(split(df,1:nrow(df))))
```